# can't create groups in fosuserbundle symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I followed the steps in the official docs to implement groups but when I go to localhost/8000/group/new and submit a group name i get "Unrecognized field: name". Any ideas?

Here is the groups attribute in Usuario.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_user_group",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $groups;
```

Group.php class

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 protected $id;

  /**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}
```

### Here is the complete stack trace

[1] Doctrine\ORM\ORMException: Unrecognized field: name
    at n/a
        in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/ORMException.php line 100

```
at Doctrine\ORM\ORMException::unrecognizedField('name')
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1686

at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->getSelectConditionStatementColumnSQL('name', null)
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1615

at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->getSelectConditionStatementSQL('name', 'asdf', null)
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1706

at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->getSelectConditionSQL(array('name' => 'asdf'), null)
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1115

at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->getSelectSQL(array('name' => 'asdf'), null, '0', '1', null, null)
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 746

at Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->load(array('name' => 'asdf'), null, null, array(), '0', '1', null)
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php line 196

at Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository->findOneBy(array('name' => 'asdf'))
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Doctrine/GroupManager.php line 55

at FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\GroupManager->findGroupBy(array('name' => 'asdf'))
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Model/GroupManager.php line 36

at FOS\UserBundle\Model\GroupManager->findGroupByName('asdf')
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Controller/GroupController.php line 115

at FOS\UserBundle\Controller\GroupController->findGroupBy('name', 'asdf')
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Controller/GroupController.php line 41

at FOS\UserBundle\Controller\GroupController->showAction('asdf')
    in  line 

at call_user_func_array(array(object(GroupController), 'showAction'), array('asdf'))
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3093

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3055

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3206

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2428

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/web/app_dev.php line 28

at require('/Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/web/app_dev.php')
    in /Users/usuario/Dropbox/uvg/6º semestre/Ingenieria de Software/Ejercicios/cemaco/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/router_dev.php line 36
```

Answer (score 1):

Group is a reserved SQL word, you can escape it in the @Table annotation :

```
@Table(name="`group`")
```

But it would definitely be better to change it to something else.